# "To go in for sport" or just "to do sport"?

Tags: british-english, collocations

At school I was taught that the collocation "to go in for sport" should be used when speaking about doing sport (e.g. to go in for karate). Is it widely-used nowadays?

Comment: Note the expression "to go in for a sport" is purely BrE and would not be commonly used in the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase *to go in for karate* sounds old fashioned to me. The meaning is clear, though.

Depending on context, it is more common to say:

- I will be taking karate. [school context]
- I do karate on Tuesdays and Fridays. [at a private facility; though you could use "take karate" here as well]
- I practice karate on weekends with friends.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the expression. It is not common in spoken or written British English. It may have had some limited use in schoolboy slang from the 1930s. However, a [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=go+in+for+karate&oq=go+in+for+karate&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22go+in+for+karate%22) shows the use to be largely limited to Russian speakers.

It seems that this is a case of Russian textbooks copying each other, rather than referring to actual usage in English.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I confused your expression with

> "to go in for *the* sport *(of it)*"

which means to join in for the excitement (the *sport*).

One can certainly "do sports" for "*the* sport of it", but if a person is participating in sports the plain way to say this is

> they do karate

Answer (score 1):

To me "go in for" is a rather colloquial and a bit old-fashioned way of saying "like doing", with a hint that the activity is a bit strange.

Looking at it on COHA (Corpus of Historical American English), the number of instances recorded per decade are:

```
1900s  45
1910s  45
1920s  52
1930s  78
1940s  41
1950s  53
1960s  43
1970s  36
1980s  36
1990s  18
2000s  18
```

So it would appear to be on the way out. I suggest you don't use it.